# Error in batch insert on memory optimized table SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016

I got this error on c# log when try to bulk insert on memory-optimized table SQL Server 2016.

> InsertDeliveries:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I've changed memory grant to 25% and Solved the problem.but after one weak this error happened again:(